# Levels in xcode (swift)

Tags: xcode, swift

I have start programming a simple game. I don't use sprite Kit because it's very simple to use sprite Kit. But I have a problem with the levels. For now I'm using a lot of UIviews for levels, if level 1 is completed the next UIView with the second level is shown. Are UIViews a good idea for Levels ? Or is there a better way to add levels in simple game ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's rather a very bad idea to use `UIView`s as adding subviews and removing them can make your game sloppy. Instead what you should do is create a new `ViewController` and according to the levels you can set the level and other properties in the `prepareForSegue` method. I am listing some links here which will help you to learn about the topics :

- [Multiple ViewControllers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AQXWsDNno8o)
- [Segues](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=18471)